# http:// no longer working after changing URL of my Bitnami Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2, bitnami

I followed this tutorial to have my Bitnami Wordpress (EC2 Linux Instance) appear on my own URL:
http://wiki.bitnami.com/Applications/BitNami_Wordpress_Stack#How_to_change_the_WordPress_domain_name.3f

It worked in that my blog now appears at: 
    **www.myURL.com**

However, it does not appear at 
    **http://www.myURL.com**

Also, many of the plug-ins no longer work, images do not display correctly, and links (e.g. to old posts or other sections/sites return 500 errors).

How can I solve this (ideally via SSH)?

EDIT:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'MYURL.com'); 
define('WP_HOME', 'MYURL.com');
```

Comment: Please post the "define('WP_SITEURL', ..." and "define('WP_HOME', ..." lines from wp-config.php

Comment: define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://www.MYURL.com');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://www.MYURL.com');

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the link you provided, you'll see that in both of those define statements you need the http:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://MYURL.com'); 
define('WP_HOME', 'http://MYURL.com');
```